# Activating hover on 2 elements to change at the same time

Tags: css, hover

How would I get these to change at the same time?

The hover works here, the .circle just needs to be connected with the .play so they are in sync.

https://jsfiddle.net/cv91gzbp/1/

```
 .jacket-left .circle:hover  {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 44px;
  height: 44px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0 0 10px;
}

 .jacket-left .play:hover {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 24.2px;
  height: 41.8px;
  fill: red;
}
```

I have this, but can't figure out how to get it to work with the above code.

or maybe for the above code it would be written differently than this.

```
.jacket-left .circle:hover,
.jacket-left .circle:hover .play path{
     border: 1px solid red;
     fill: red;
 }
```

Comment: you want the same hover effect on the right play buttom ?

Comment: or you want the hover effect when hovering over circle ot  play not just at play ?

Comment: Only on they left one. I'm trying to get it to work on that one.

Comment: So the problem is that the effect only work on the left element right?

Comment: The problem is, when the .circle is hovered on the left element the .play in the middle doesn't change at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
.jacket-left .play:hover
```

To this:

```
 .jacket-left .circle:hover .play
```

Now when `circle` is hovered the hover effect of circle will be applied and the svg `play` size will increase.

See [Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/me1cfyhw/)